# Is it necessary to have "blog" somewhere in the URL for a blog for SEO?

Tags: seo, url, blog

I am developing a website which will have only blogs, about us page, and contact page. The homepage is listing of all blogs.

Should have include **blog** in the URL like `example.com/blog/sample-slug` or would `example.com/sample-slug` be fine? How would this affect SEO?

Comment: There is absolutely not difference between your two example URLs. Do whichever is preferred or easier. Please do not sweat unnecessary details in the name of SEO. The whole SEO thing has really taken on ridiculous proportions and scale. Understand much of what your will see online regarding SEO will be pure unadulterated bull squirt created by non-technical people who really have no idea how search engines work. Cheers!!

Comment: With "blogs", you mean *blog posts* (not multiple separate blogs), right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually better to have as clean of a URL as possible. And for that reason, in most cases, I would not add /blog/ to your URLs.

If you are really trying to rank your website for the keyword "blog", then this might be an acceptable practice to add /blog/ to your URLs.

Allowing the blog posts to have cleaner URLs without the directory could incentivise users to write more. It could also allow you to have a higher click through rate on Google.

Comment: Right, That's what I was also thinking. Having `blog` in the url would simply tell people that it's a blog. In future if I would add more sections and pages in my website, the blog url would also look like a page which would be quite odd. And in future I wouldn't risk to change the URL scheme of them as that would affect the SEO.

Answer (score 1):

If the website is for something else (e.g. an e-commerce site) and the blog is a part of it, then yes have 'blog' in the URL. If the whole website is a blog then you probably won't need it. There are far more important details to consider.

Comment: My concern is when in future If I add more sections and pages, the blog url would look like a page, and changing url that time would be a big loss to SEO.

Comment: How do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

For sure it's not necessary have to name blog in URL. It's good for you and user.
If have some effect you probably don't realize it the effect.